# How to stop propagation of & functions into nested directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

here I got one ctrl

```
controllers.ctrl = function($scope){

 $scope.trData = [
  {name : 'elem1',children : []},
  {name : 'elem2',children : 
     [{name : 'elem3',children : []}]
  }
 };


 $scope.testFunction = function(tr){
  console.debug(tr);
 }
}
```

And a nested directive

```
directives.nested = function($compile){
  restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,        
    scope: {
        tr: '=',
        test : '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {  

        scope.setActive = function(){
            console.debug("A");
            console.debug(scope.tr);
            scope.test({tr:scope.tr});
            console.debug("B");
        };

        var template = '<span data-ng-click="setActive();">{{tr.name}} - </span>';

        if(scope.tr.children.length > 0){
            template += '<ul><li data-ng-repeat="tr0 in tr.children">';
            template += '<nested  tr="tr0" test="test(tr)"></nested>';
            template += '</li></ul>';
        }
        var newElement = angular.element(template);
        $compile(newElement)(scope);
        element.replaceWith(newElement);
}
```

And in my template, of course :

```
<ul>
 <li data-ng-repeat="tr in trData">
  <nested tr="tr" test="testFunction(tr)"></nested>
 </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on a elem1, I've got in the console:

```
A
{name : 'elem1',children : []}
B
```

If I click on 'elem3', I got

```
A
{name : 'elem3',children : []}
{name : 'elem2',children : [{name : 'elem3',children : []}] }
B
```

The function testFunction is called twice. I would like to have it called only once with elem3.

I am sure there is a better way to do this.

Fiddle from Banana-In-Black : http://jsfiddle.net/T4uKf/

Comment: can you show this issue into Fiddle/Plunker?

Comment: @MaximShoustin I copy/pasted the Fiddle from 'Banana-In-Black'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

> Try to click on elem3 : You will see the console.debug output 'Object
>   {name: "elem3", children: Array[0]' And the console.warn outputs :
>   Object {name: "elem2", children: Array[1] I though I would had "elem3"
>   output twice. Instead I got "elem3" and "elem2". Do you know why this
>   happens?

To anwser this, first we take a look on generated HTML and scope:

```
                                                <!-- controller scope       -->
<li data-ng-repeat=" tr in trData ">            <!--1|-child scope          -->
    <span>elem2 - </span>                       <!--2  |-isolated scope     -->
    <ul>                                        <!--     |                  -->
        <li data-ng-repeat="tr0 in tr.children"><!--3    |-child scope      -->
            <span>elem3</span>                  <!--4      |-isolated scope -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The variables in scope will be like: (`|-` stands for inheritance)

- Controller Scope: `{ trData: [...] }`

  - |- Scope1 (child): `{ tr0: elem2 }`
- Scope2 (isolated): `{ tr: elem2, test: function() }`

  - |- Scope3 (child): `{ tr0: elem3 }`
- Scope4 (isolated): `{ tr: elem3, test: function() }`

Now, according to [official api docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile), which talks about isolated scope variable:

> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope.

* This feature is implemented by `$parse` service.

After you clicked on `elem3`, the execution order will be: (skip the log part.)

1. `test({ tr: scope.tr })` using `Scope4` as its execution context

   - Equals to `$parse('test(tr)')(Scope3, { tr: elem3 })`.
   - It's called in `Scope3` because `$parse` executes in parent scope.
2. `test(tr)` using `Scope3` as its execution context

   - Equals to `$parse('testFunction(tr)')(Scope1, elem3)`
   - It's called in `Scope1` because test() is inherited from `Scope2`, and `$parse` executes in parent scope.
3. `testFunction(tr)` using `Scope1` as its execution context

   - Now tr will be parsed into `Scope1.tr` which is `elem2` because `elem3.tr` doesn't exist.
4. Finally, `console.warn(elem2)`;

This is how that happens...

* About $parse service you can check [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse).

---

### Origin:

I changed `console.log` to `console.warn`, ang log shows it only executed once.

```
 $scope.testFunction = function (tr) {
     console.warn(tr);
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T4uKf/

It prints twice

```
A
{name : 'elem3',children : []}
{name : 'elem2',children : [{name : 'elem3',children : []}] }
B
```

only because you log it in both `scope.setActive` and `$scope.testFunction()`

Comment: Thanks very much for the Fiddle. I was going to create one, but got no time.
Try to click on elem3 : You will see the console.debug output 'Object {name: "elem3", children: Array[0]'
And the console.warn outputs : 
Object {name: "elem2", children: Array[1]

I though I would had "elem3" output twice. Instead I got "elem3" and "elem2". Do you know why this happens?

Comment: I got it the parent Scope, but I still don't understand why the {tr:value} parameter is rewritten with elem2. Do you have any example around where I could call the controller's function with the value  of the clicked directive's tr?